# Recover result after "Set" error

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, output

I have a function `someFunction[]` that takes a long time to evaluate. I would like to run

```
{time, result} = Timing@someFunction[];
```

to also measure the execution time. Instead, I forgot to include `Timing@` and wrote

```
{time, result} = someFunction[];
```

This ran for a long time, but right at the end when the value was supposed to be assigned a "`Set: Lists {time, result} and <<1>> are not the same shape.`" error was thrown, and I got nothing out. Is there a way to still recover the result of the computation? It would be a shame if there wasn't - the result was already computed, and just the assignment failed.

Comment: in 11.2 there should be a menu next to the error message with a "show stack" item.

Comment: Hm, strange, thought of it as well, but when I was looking for it when I had the error and I swear it wasn't there. Are there cases where "Show Stack" doesn't appear in the pop-up?

Comment: Just a side note, I always prefer to do something like `timing = AbsoluteTiming[ result = someFunction[] ];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment:

```
$Line=0;
{a, b} = (Pause[1]; 10);

Out[1]
```

> Set::shape: Lists {a,b} and 10 are not the same shape.
>
> 10

Comment: Hi Carl, that's true, however, if the output of the function is long then parts of it are shortened to `<<1>>` and you can't copy-paste them any more.

Comment: @Stan I don't understand. `Out[n]` always contains the full output, it does not contain any shorteners.

Comment: Hi Carl, sorry, I misread your reply. That's interesting - no "Out" cell is produced, but it's still created behind the scenes, and it contains the output I'm looking for. That's good to know. Thanks!